# Good RNG for shuffling playing cards

Tags: c++, random

Right now I'm using the Mersenne Twister RNG and performing Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm 100 times:

```
    std::vector<Card> shufCards;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 13; ++j)
        {

            shufCards.push_back(Card((Card::SuitEnum)i,(Card::RankEnum)j));
        }
    }
    for(int r = 0; r < 100; ++r)
    for(int i = shufCards.size() - 1; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        int j = m_randomGenerator.genrand_int31() % (i + 1);
        std::swap(shufCards[i],shufCards[j]);
    }

    std::vector<Card> cards;
    for(int i = 0; i < zeroBasedCut; ++i)
    {
        cards.push_back(shufCards[i]);
    }

    for(int i = zeroBasedCut; i < 52; ++i)
    {
        cards.push_back(shufCards[i]);
    }


    return cards;
```

But it feels like the amount of cards per suit is off and somewhat predictable. It is highly unlikely to have a hand of 13 cards with just 1 heart and 5 spades but this happens rather often.

What is a better RNG I could use for this?

Thanks

Comment: Why is it highly unlikely? Having a hand of 3/3/3/4, now *that* would be highly unlikely. Human intuitive perception of randomness is very very bad.

Comment: There really isn't any reason to shuffle 100 times. If the algorithm is correct then once is sufficient. You could also use the `std::random_shuffle` that's in the standard library.

Comment: As Blastfurnace says, shuffling more than once is not necessary.  The "cut" is also completely unnecessary.  With a human shuffling, there is a chance that you accidentally see the bottom card, so the cut buries that card in the middle of the deck.  The cut is traditionally done by someone who's not the dealer, so it provides some protection against a dealer trying to fix the deck.  With a computer shuffling, neither of those apply - the cut is completely unnecessary.

Comment: You often get "like" 4,5,3,1?  Or you often get "exactly" 4,5,3,1?  Because often getting something "like" 4,5,3,1 is not at all unlikely.  But if, hand after hand, you get those same four cards, that's a different story.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Our perception of randomness is notoriously poor. If you suspect that your routine is skewed in some way, I'd recommend conducting a large number of random trials using your routine and then looking at the realized probabilities of various hand distributions, and comparing them with what is to be expected theoretically.

Other than this, I've got a couple of observations:

1. Why shuffle multiple times? One pass should do as good a job.
2. What's the purpose of `zeroBasedCut`? What does it achieve that Fisher-Yates doesn't?
3. Why not use `std::random_shuffle` instead of your own routine?

Answer (score 2):

There are three parts to good randomness:

1. A good source of entropy for the seed.
2. A good PRNG.
3. Good algorithms to use the randomness.

For a card game, Mersenne Twister and Fisher-Yates shuffle are both fine.  If you're getting repeatable results, I suspect you have a poor source of entropy.  Are you seeding the RNG?